# Ubuntu 20 Dell T3610 crashes, is this disk/partition problem?

Tags: partitioning

Running Ubuntu 20 on Dell T3610 but crashing when PC is working hard.
Temperatures look OK.

Having reinstalled Ubuntu a few times am worried that I have an unstable file system?

[image: disk error?]

---

Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS

the hard work is running molecular dynamics simulations using [GROMACS](https://www.gromacs.org/About_Gromacs). The crashing is that the PC turns off and reboots itself

This is not however only specific to running simulations. I can be using the terminal for something basic and opening chrome will cause the PC to switch off and restart.

looking at vim syslog I get the below (is there a better way to check for errors?)

```
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (II) systemd-logind: returning pre-existing fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (**) SEMICO USB Keyboard Consumer Control: always reports core events
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (**) Option "_source" "_driver/libinput"
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (II) libinput: SEMICO USB Keyboard Consumer Control: is a virtual subdevice
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.1/0003:145F:01E5.0002/input/input3/event3"
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SEMICO USB Keyboard Consumer Control" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1184]: /usr/bin/prime-supported: 38: cannot create /var/log/prime-supported.log: Permission denied
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: /sbin/prime-offload: 29: cannot create /var/log/prime-offload.log: Permission denied
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activating service name='org.a11y.Bus' requested by ':1.0' (uid=125 pid=1188 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-check-accelerated " label="unconfined")
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.Bus'
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.3' (uid=125 pid=1187 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd --auto" label="unconfined")
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.4' (uid=125 pid=1187 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd --auto" label="unconfined")
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 gnome-session[1187]: gnome-session-binary[1187]: WARNING: Falling back to non-systemd startup procedure due to error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 gnome-session-binary[1187]: WARNING: Falling back to non-systemd startup procedure due to error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.4' (uid=125 pid=1187 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd --auto" label="unconfined")
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.4' (uid=125 pid=1187 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd --auto" label="unconfined")
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.4' (uid=125 pid=1187 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd --auto" label="unconfined")
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.4' (uid=125 pid=1187 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd --auto" label="unconfined")
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.4' (uid=125 pid=1187 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd --auto" label="unconfined")
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
```

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  No such release, so do you mean Ubuntu Core 20 as the *year* format is used only for *snap* only releases.  (the main releases are *year.month* in format, eg. 20.04 or 20.10)   You've provided no details as to what you see in logs, whether it's a GUI crash? (ie. terminal or SysRq commands will still work) or kernel crash (not even linux kernel SysRq commands will work, and logs won't show much - ie. likely hardware issue)  If you're worried about disk & using a normal (non 20 snap only) release you can check - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: Can you describe the crash? Is this the system rebooting itself or an application that is crashing. What does "working hard" mean for your computer? Games? Data manipulation? Compiling code? Mining Bitcoin? Help us help you by supplying as much detail as you can 

Comment: There is nothing to suggest a disk error in the picture you have posted.

Comment: Edit your question and show me screenshot(s) of the `Disks` app **SMART Data** window (this data is scrollable, so it may take 2 screenshots). Also show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS

the hard work is running molecular dynamics simulations using GROMACS https://www.gromacs.org/About_Gromacs

the crashing is that the PC turns off and reboots itself

This is not however only specific to running simulations. I can be using the terminal for something basic and opening chrome will cause the PC to switch off and restart.

looking at vim syslog I get the below (is there a better way to check for errors?)

```
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (II) systemd-logind: returning pre-existing fd for /dev/input/event3 13:67
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (**) SEMICO USB Keyboard Consumer Control: always reports core events
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (**) Option "_source" "_driver/libinput"
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (II) libinput: SEMICO USB Keyboard Consumer Control: is a virtual subdevice
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.1/0003:145F:01E5.0002/input/input3/event3"
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SEMICO USB Keyboard Consumer Control" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1184]: /usr/bin/prime-supported: 38: cannot create /var/log/prime-supported.log: Permission denied
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1182]: /sbin/prime-offload: 29: cannot create /var/log/prime-offload.log: Permission denied
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activating service name='org.a11y.Bus' requested by ':1.0' (uid=125 pid=1188 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-check-accelerated " label="unconfined")
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.Bus'
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.3' (uid=125 pid=1187 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd --auto" label="unconfined")
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.4' (uid=125 pid=1187 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd --auto" label="unconfined")
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 gnome-session[1187]: gnome-session-binary[1187]: WARNING: Falling back to non-systemd startup procedure due to error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 gnome-session-binary[1187]: WARNING: Falling back to non-systemd startup procedure due to error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.4' (uid=125 pid=1187 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd --auto" label="unconfined")
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.4' (uid=125 pid=1187 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd --auto" label="unconfined")
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.4' (uid=125 pid=1187 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd --auto" label="unconfined")
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.4' (uid=125 pid=1187 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd --auto" label="unconfined")
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.systemd1' requested by ':1.4' (uid=125 pid=1187 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-binary --systemd --auto" label="unconfined")
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1186]: dbus-daemon[1186]: [session uid=125 pid=1186] Activated service 'org.freedesktop.systemd1' failed: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 330.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
Jul 21 08:14:47 T3610 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1017]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
```

Comment: You should really add this information to your question. An answer will discourage people from taking the time to read the question. Also please format the syslog log as code. It will be much easier to read